# AES encryption and decryption causes data corruption

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, cryptography

I am using the [tiny-AES-c library](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) to encrypt a Qt ByteArray, but the encryption or the decryption is not working as expected and at the end of the decryption I do not get the unencrypted ByteArray.

The code I am using is this:

```
    void MainWindow::compressImageWithEncryption()
{
    qDebug() << "compressImageWithEncryption";

    //grabbing a screenshot of the desktop
    auto img = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId()).toImage();

    //saving the screenshot as a JPG formated byte array
    QByteArray bytes;
    QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    img.save(&buffer, "JPG");

    //displaying the screenshot to the ui
    auto img_from_bytes = QImage::fromData(bytes, "JPG");
    ui->lblDesktop->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img_from_bytes));

    //compress the screenshot byte array
    QByteArray compressed_bytes = qCompress(bytes,9);

    //settings encryption key and iv
    const uint8_t key[] = { 0x60, 0x3d, 0xeb, 0x10, 0x15, 0xca, 0x71, 0xbe, 0x2b, 0x73, 0xae, 0xf0, 0x85, 0x7d, 0x77, 0x81,
                      0x1f, 0x35, 0x2c, 0x07, 0x3b, 0x61, 0x08, 0xd7, 0x2d, 0x98, 0x10, 0xa3, 0x09, 0x14, 0xdf, 0xf4 };

    const uint8_t iv[]  = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };

    //encrypt compressed bytes
    std::vector<uint8_t> encrypted_bytes(compressed_bytes.size());
    auto uint8_compressed_bytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(compressed_bytes.data());
    AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(
                encrypted_bytes.data(),
                uint8_compressed_bytes,
                compressed_bytes.size(),
                key,
                iv
                );
    //ok encryption is done.


    //decrypt compressed bytes
    std::vector<uint8_t> decrypted_bytes(encrypted_bytes.size());
    AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(
                decrypted_bytes.data(),
                encrypted_bytes.data(),
                encrypted_bytes.size(),
                key,
                iv
                );
    //ok decryption is done.

    //uncompress the encrypted compressed bytes
    auto uncompressed_bytes = qUncompress(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(decrypted_bytes.data()),decrypted_bytes.size());
    qDebug() << "uncompressed_bytes size:" << uncompressed_bytes.size();

    qDebug() << "compressImageWithEncryption completed";
}
```

What this code does is that it takes a screenshot of the desktop, compressed it, encrypts it, decrypts it and then uncompresses it.
However at the uncompression step I am getting the error: **qUncompress: Z_DATA_ERROR: Input data is corrupted**. 
What am I doing wrong here?
You can download the complete Qt project from this link https://www.sendspace.com/file/3j6qbi

Comment: Make sure you're encrypting/decrypting 16 byte blocks (round up to be modulo 16) and pay extra care to the last block of 16 bytes to ensure the bytes not used by the compressed output are put to a known value.

Comment: If the above code is a copy paste from your program the use of the encrypt function `AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer` for both encrypt and decrypt could be a potential source of your problem, as I don't think it is a symmetrical function. Looking in the `test.c` of tiny-AES-c they use `AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer` to encrypt and `AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer` to decrypt.

Comment: @geoff3jones yes, it looks that this was the problem. Do you know if it is ok to pass a pointer to the array or should I encrypt/decrypt the byte array in 16 bytes blocks as Russ Schultz suggest?

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis I'm glad that helped, yes I would follow the advice of Russ above and make sure that the string to encrypt is modulo 16 bytes, you can just pad the end of the array with zeros as suggested on line 28 of aes.c. Passing in a pointer should be fine (though will probably render the `compressed_bytes` as garbage) just remember to pad the QByteArray after you set the compressed data.